# MOO: Variable is both a decision variable and an objective

Tags: optimization, multi-objective-optimization

I'm trying to solve a Multi-Objective Optimization Problem to find the set of Pareto Optimal Solutions. I have a list of decision variables (x1, x2, x3) and a list of objectives (o1, o2, x3). As you can see, one of the variables is both a decision variable and an objective. Is this a good way to formulate this problem or are there more efficient ways to do it? Also, are you aware of any research that look into problems that have a variable as both a decision variable and objective?

Comment: Welcome to OR.SE. What exactly you mean by `one of the variables is both a decision variable and an objective`? Is your problem an LP/MIP or do you have another special form of the term in the third objective function?

Comment: A decision variable is a variable that will be either part of objective function like $f(x)=x $ or part of constraints with impact on the solution space of other decision variables. In other words you need to find a solution of values for decision variables that will give the optimal objective value.

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong (or inefficient) with having one of the objective functions be the value of a decision variable.